# Deployment file size of a IEAK package

Tags: internet-explorer

I created a very simple IEAK package that adds a single site to users Local Intranet Zone. The size of the package is 36MB! The ins file is only 2KBs. Having to send this large file for only one setting seems strange to me. Is there a way to make the package smaller?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately yes, IEAK creates an offline installer. An option you can go with is making the change through GPO instead of pushing down and entire installer.

Comment: Thanks Zypher. We can't do it with a GPO because AFAIK Local Intranet Zone settings for Internet Explorer 8 & 9 cannot be done with GPO. Is that right?

Comment: Looks like you can set 8 but not 9 at this point User Settings -> Preferences -> Internet Settings